# MvvmCross: Cannot install Zxing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, zxing

I have a Xamarin.Android project with these packages:

- Acr.UserDialogs 7.0.1
- MvvmCross 6.1.2
- MvvmCross.CodeAnalysis 6.1.2
- MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Design 6.1.2
- MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat 6.1.2
- Xam.Plugin.Connectivity 3.2.0
- Xam.Plugins.Settings 3.1.1
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout 1.1.2

When i try to install ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.4.1 (lastest version) in Xamarin.Android project, then i get these exception:

*Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2 directly to project WarehouseMS.Droid to resolve this issue. 
WarehouseMS.Droid -> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat 6.1.2 -> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment 6.1.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 27.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) 
 WarehouseMS.Droid -> ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.4.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.1).*

**Update**

When i install ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.3.2, then I get that there are several versions of DrawerLayout and can't specify this:

The type 'DrawerLayout' exists in both 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' WarehouseMS.Droid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems manually by installing these packages:

- Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat

With MvvmCross, version 27.0.2 was installed, and when upgrading I install 27.0.2.1